# Can I source a php file as javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using a WP template that allows me to incorporate arbitrary HTML.  Unfortunately, I have to use this particular widget and can't use other WP widgets.

I have on my webserver /some/path/serve_image.php that spits out a random HREF'd IMG SRC with a caption and some other info from a MySQL query.

Now...how can I say "take that output and treat it as HTML"?  If I just put "/some/path/serve_image.php" I get that literal string.

I tried:

```
<script type="javascript" src="/some/path/serve_image.php"></script>
```

but that didn't work.  I tried changing everything in serve_image.php to be document.write() calls and that didn't seem to work either.  I'm not the world's greatest JS guy...

So if I have a URL on the net that spits out some HTML and I want to include that HTML in my web page, what's the best way to do that?  Sort of like what Google does with Adsense - you source their show_ads.js.

Comment: Are you using plain JavaScript or a framework like jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Why no? Add

> header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

And output JavaScript Like:

```
echo("var image = \"".$images[array_rand($images)]."\";");
echo("$('img.randim').attr('src', image);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript and PHP are two completely separate languages. In fact, if it was JavaScript, you aren't even loading it the right way.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The way you're trying to do it would throw a parse error, because it would try to use the PHP as JavaScript. Some browsers would even reject it, because PHP files have a `text/html` MIME type, while JavaScript should be `application/javascript`.

PHP has to be done server side, so loading it in the client just doesn't work.

What I think you're after is this:

```
<?php

    require('/some/path/serve_image.php');

?>
```

Just place that wherever you want the image to be.

Comment: That won't really work, because it needs to be placed in a certain spot in the page.  But forget for the moment that it's PHP.  What if it was just HTML?  Is there a way to have a JS that says "source this URL over here and print out the HTML it produces"?

Comment: @raindog: You can move the `require` statement to wherever you want it. for a JS solution, load up a framework or break out some cross-browser XHR skills.

Comment: The MIME type issue isn't quite valid. You can use PHP files to output JS just fine. If you're worried about MIME types, all you need to do is set a `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');`, and the browser won't know the difference between the PHP file and a normal JS file. However, you obviously do need to output valid JavaScript, so you're not totally off :)

Comment: @yc Just did some testing. Chrome doesn't care for the MIME type.

Comment: @tylermwashburn : `PHP has to be done server side, so loading it in the client just doesn't work`... no one said that it wants the php to be compiled on the client, it just needs the outputted result(after the server side part is done)

Comment: @gion If the server has to compile it, and output the HTML, why would you waste client resources to over complicate your code?

Comment: @tylermwashburn : I'm not saying it is the best solution : the point was that it does work. I can think (without struggling) of a few scenarios where it's better to use a client-side technique to load some elements from server

Comment: @gion I can too. Like when you want different things to be loaded based on user input, or when you want things to be changed on an interval.